# redirection and vim

Tags: linux, vim

I was wondering if there's a way to see the output of any command,
straight inside vim, rather than first redirecting it into  a file and
then opening that file.

E.x. I need something like
$  gvim < `diff -r dir1/ dir2/`

This gives ambiguous redirect error message

I just want to see the diffs between dir1 and dir2 straight inside
gvim.

Can any one provide a nice hack?

Answer (score 42):

```
diff file1 file2 | vim -R -
```

The `-R` makes it read-only so you don't accidentally modify the input (which may or may not be your desired behavior).  The single dash tells `vim` to reads its input over standard input.  Works for other commands, too.

Answer (score 10):

Also, when already in Vim:

```
:r! diff file1 file2
```

Answer (score 6):

`vim -d file1 file2`

Answer (score 6):

Although I would also suggest `vimdiff` or `vim -d` for the case of looking at a diff, I just have to share this (more general) approach for using vim usage in pipes: vipe (from the `moreutils` package in Ubuntu).

For example:

> find -name '*.png' | vipe | xargs rm

would allow you to first edit (in vim) the list of .png files found before passing it to `xargs rm`.

Answer (score 4):

jst use gvimdiff instead
or vimdiff 
to paste the output of a command straight into vim, for example ls, try
:%r!ls

Comment: If you have an alias on `vim` (to a custom installation, maybe), `vimdiff` will use the site-wide vim.  You can use `vim -d` (or set up another alias) to get "diff" behavior with your custom vim.

Answer (score 4):

BTW, there is a [DirDiff plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=102).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with

```
diff -r dir1/ dir2/ | gvim -
```

the '`-`' option to vim (or gvim) tells vim to open STDIN

Answer (score 1):

I often use `vimdiff -g <file1> <file2>`

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simple and convenient ways is to do it like this:

```
vimdiff -R <file1> <file2>
```

Again the '-R' flag is to open it for read-only mode to avoid any accidental changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

`vim <(diff -r dir1/ dir2/)`

But the DirDiff plugin mentioned by Luc is much more useful for comparing directories.